# Receive non blocking messages in tcp sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to make a little LAN chat in Java, I have a thread that loops through a list with all the clients and tries to read the next line with `0` set as the timeout.

```
while(true){
    for(ChatClient chater : Server.connections){
        try{
                chater.sock.setSoTimeout(0);
                message = SocketUtils.recvMsg(chater.sock);
                System.out.println(chater.getName() + " has sent a message!");

                message = chater.getName() + ": " + message;
                senderId = chater.getId();

                Server.broadcastMsg(message, senderId);
            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException e1){

                continue;
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                //
            }
                    
        }
}
```

I am pretty sure that the bug is between the bug is because the non-blocking sockets aren't implemented correctly.

What would be the best way to receive messages from the users without blocking the loop?

Thanks for taking your time answering the question!

Comment: Just use another thread?

Comment: @dan1st  This snippet is running in another thread, but for some reason, the sockets aren't receiving anything.